# Specifying random slope in R: what is the difference between (Days | Subject) and (1 + Days | Subject)?

Tags: r, lme4-nlme

I am reading [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1406.5823.pdf) paper for fitting mixed models.

I and was wondering what is the difference between:

```
fm2 <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (Days | Subject), sleepstudy)
fm2 <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (1 + Days | Subject), sleepstudy)
```

Could anyone explain this in a simple way and which one should be used?

Comment: Did you try to run the commands? There is no difference.

Comment: Yes I did and you are right there's no difference. I thought  there was something that the models do internally different when formula is specified separately like that.

Comment: Note also that fm2 <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (Days | Subject), sleepstudy) === fm2 <- lmer(Reaction ~ 1 + Days + (Days | Subject), sleepstudy)